# @Transaction does not work for multiple inner methods of same class or when called methods of another classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-transactions

I have a method which is annotated with @Transactional , which internally calling multiple inner method for same class which within them may or may not be calling any other external service methods. When it is calling the external service class method , it is working for 1 method meanning it rollbacking , but same service  when calling another method of same class [external service class only ] , it is no roll backing , can anyone help me here.

```
  @Transactional 
  public void processPayments(PaymentRequest request) { 
    request.getDetails.forEach(payment -> {
                method1(payment);
    });
   // when doSomething1() is success , then its calling below method ,
   externalService.doSomething2();// when it api fails , it is rollbacking properly , the process of calling is exactly same. Howcome this is rollbacking not dosomething1() is not rollbacking ?

}

private void method1(PaymentDetails details){
    details.getDetails.forEach(detailedPayment -> {
                method1_1(detailedPayment);
            });

    task3();
}

private void method1_1(DetailedPayment detailedPayment){
    roundPayment();
    task1();
    task2();
}

private void roundPayment(){

}

private SomeObject task1(SomeObjet object){
    // update object with if conditions 
    repository.save(object);
}

private SomeObject task2(){
    // update object with if conditions 
    repository.save(object);
}


private SomeObject task3(){
    // repository.save(updateSomeObject(someObject));
    // externalService.doSomething1(double val1 , double val2); // this is another service , which also uses another service , which uses restTemplate to call external service. , if http status is other than 200 , i am throwing ExternalAPICall Exception , which should roll back full transaction starting from processPayments method 
    // its not roll backing 
}

private void updateSomeObject(SomeObject object){
    // update object based on few if conditions
}
```

Can anyone help me here ? Also i would like to know more about properly use of transactional , like multiple inner method of same class , or  multiple inner method of another classe called by proxied class and so on.

Comment: Which database are you using and is not everything being rolledback or things partially? It will only rollback things in the DB modifications made through HTTP requests won't be rolled back!.

Comment: Mysql , if HTTP requests returns other than 200,201 i have to rollback entire transaction starting from 1st method, I have dependency on external calls. I can first call external and then my local java code , but requirement is to execute local java code fully , come up with final values and then calls external service with calculated values , it all good , then only commit the transaction . I am calling 2 Http service for now , it might increase as well. external servie has there own db , my application has its own db

Comment: You cannot rollback external services, you don't control those (from your application). If you are using MySQL make sure you are using InnoDB tables and not MyISAM tables!.

Comment: yes i agree that i do not have control. I just want to rollback my transaction if i am not getting 200 from the api call. If its not 200 , i am throwing custom exception , which should rollback transaction. It working for 1 method but not for another of same class. I am using innoDB tables only

Comment: You only have 1 public method, so not sure which other method you are considering? Also calling the same method from within the same class will ignore the `@Transactional` as it isn't passing through the proxy. Also make sure your custom exception is a `RuntimeException` or your `@Transactional` is configured to rollback on your custom exception if it isn't a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: yes i have extended RuntimeException, I have only 1 public method which is annotated with @Transactional , rest everything is private method which internally applying some logic. out of which 2 private method is calling externalService , when one is throwing 400 (BadRequest) ,i say throw new ExternalServiceException,  its rollbacking transaction where in another method on 400 is not roll backing thats only the issue.

Comment: As stated make sure you are using the proper table type. The psuedo code shwon here should work, so I expect your code isn't the same and the problem lies somewhere in the differences between this and your code.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have exact copied code , just renamed methods, yes it working properly but 1 method where externalService.doSomething1() is called , when i throw custom excpetion its not roll backing , same way externalService.doSomething2() is called , but its rollbacked , what could be possible way that first one is not getting rollbacked

Answer (score 0):

The only structural difference between calling `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` is that the first one is called form inside a inlined function. (which is passed to a stream, which could be implemented some fancy asynchronous way.)

What happens if you refactor your code this way :

```
  @Transactional 
  public void processPayments(PaymentRequest request) { 
    for(PaymentDetails details: request.getDetails()) {
      method1(details);
    }
    externalService.doSomething2();
  }
```

(If it works, refactor the other method too, there is good chance that task1 and task2 wont roll back neither, because `details.getDetails()` has a similar implementation.)